# JS Array findIndex() is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript

The following code produces always an error:

```
var index = this.dataSource.findIndex(item => item.id_system === row.id_system);
```

The error message is:
TypeError: this.dataSource.findIndex is not a function

What could be the solution?

Comment: null.findIndex, undefined.findIndex, {...}.findIndex, you need to have an array on findIndex, check the value of dataSource by console logging it

Comment: Is `dataSource` an array?

Comment: The solution is to make sure that `this.dataSource` is something that has a `findIndex()` function. Probably an array is what you're expecting.

Comment: [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
];

Comment: this would be an example datasource

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: How findIndex() is relates to angular it a js Array function isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Angular Material example, then you will need to use `data` array.

Your dataSource should be `MatTableDataSource<your type>`.

So maybe you can try

```
let index = this.dataSource.data.findIndex(item => item.id_system === row.id_system);
```